# Reformat the post array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a post array like below:

```
[quantity] => Array
    (
        [5] => 10
        [23] => 20
    )

[price] => Array
    (
        [5] => 100.00 $
        [23] => 200.00 $
    )

[amount] => Array
    (
        [5] => 1,000.00 $  
        [23] => 4,000.00 $ 
    )
```

5 and 23 are id of product. And i need to convert it to :

```
[5]  => Array
     (
        [quantity] => 10
        [price]    => 100.00 $
        [amount]   => 1,000.00 USD
     )
[23] = => Array
     (
        [quantity] => 20
        [price]    => 200.00 $
        [amount]   => 4,000.00 USD
     )
```

How can i achieve this efficiently so that they can be ready for mysql insert?

Comment: @Repox, `foreach ($post as $input_key => $input_values)
{
  foreach ($input_values as $field => $value)
  {
    $tmp[$field][$input_key] = $value;
  }
}`  and frankly it works but I just want to know if it is the best way.

Comment: @yahyaE if that works, it looks fine to me.

Comment: The solutions seems reasonable - short and simple. I like it.

Comment: @yahyaE Wouldn't that be redundant, since the array key is the product id?

Comment: @Repox, you are right, I noticed that since I press add comments so immediately delete the comment but you are fast to enough to see and answer it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walk through one of those arrays, acquire ID's and reconstruct.

Example:

```
// YOUR DATA
$quantity = array();
$price = array();
$amount = array();

// NEW ARRAY
$array = array();

foreach ($quantity as $id => $itemQty) {
   $itemPrice = $price[$id];
   $itemAmount = $amount[$id];
   $array[$id] = array("quantity" => $itemQty, "amount" => $itemAmount, "price" => $itemPrice);
}
```

Now you have your data in $array sorted as you want.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I think here, I'll be expected to dissolve array or `$quantity = $post['quantity']` shall be enpugh to proceed?

Comment: If you mean $quantity = $_POST['quantity']; Then yeas. But don't forget to acquire the other 2 arrays also.

Comment: :) yes, my mistake hence in my code, `$post = $_[POST]`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$quantity = array(5=>10,23=>20);
$price    = array(5=>'100.00$',23=>'200.00$');
$amount   = array(5=>'1000.00$',23=>'4000.00$');

$newData  = array_map(null, $quantity, $price,$amount);
$newKeys  = array_keys($quantity);
$data     = array_combine($newKeys,$newData);

echo('<pre>');
print_r($data);
```

But the array must be ordered！